# Regarding the height of a recursion tree on dynamic programming

Tags: recurrence-relation, dynamic-programming

I am trying to understand dynamic programming and I am watching this mit video. If you guys could take some time out , can you refer to the slide on 41:36 . Why is the height m+n. I just don't get it why is the heigh of this recurrence tree m+n.

http://videolectures.net/mit6046jf05_leiserson_lec15/

Thank you.

Comment: Try to make the question more self-contained: what's on the slide? Assume links will break, since often they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each level you subtract $1$ from the left *or* the right in the worst case (when $x \ne y$). So intuitively if you go down the left over and over again (along the leftmost part of the tree), it will reach $(1,n)$, at level $m$, and you will only be able to go right from there. Then you will go down $n$ more levels to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Realz Slaw, I think I get it now, I was confused, thinking that it should stop when it reaches (1,n) , because there wont be anything to compare the x[1] to y[1..n]. The psuedo code is not correct then since it does not check the case when it has reached the end of the string.